# jQuery, temporarily add class for xx milliseconds

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to temporarily add a class to an element and then remove it again after xx milliseconds?

For example;

When I click on an element with the class `.trigger` can I add a class of `.loading` to another element with a class of `.menu` and then, after say 500ms, remove the `.loading` class again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with a setTimeout like this :

```
$("MyControl").addClass("loading");
setTimeout(function () {
     $("MyControl").removeClass("loading");
},500);
```